# What is the difference between 这个 and 此?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I wonder there is any difference between two words to express `this`, `这个` and `此`. What difference, if any, is there?

Comment: (is this question not settled by dictionaries and grammars?)
这 is a demonstrative pronoun (指示代词）of modern Chinese which requires a measure word like 个 （although often used w/o one)，and 这个 can be used w/o a following noun to mean "this one" 此 is a pronoun belonging to ancient and bookish style modern C, thus is used w/o measure words (classifiers), can be used w/o following noun to mean  "now; here":
从此以后 from now on; henceforward
由此往南 go south from here, also search site for previous Q and A involving 此

Comment: in particular see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/%e6%96%af-vs-%e8%bf%99-vs-%e6%ad%a4-for-the-meaning-this

Comment: The word 此 in ancient Chinese idioms could not be replaced with 这个, like in 此话怎讲, 此情此景, these are chronic collocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - 这 is more colloquial, usually followed by a classifier
> - 此 is more literary, it does not need classifier, and more often followed by a single character word

See Examples:

此人= 這個人

此事= 這件事

此地= 這個地方

此物= 這件東西

此時= 這個時候

此刻= 這個時刻

此心= 這顆心

此案= 這宗案

The classifier after 這 can often be omitted. For example: 這個地方--> 這地方; 這件東西-->這東西.

Since classifiers work with counting words,  we can write 這一個地方; 這三件東西.

But we don't usually use counting word with 此

'此一地方' , '此三東西. just sound unnatural.

Comment: Thanks. Then how about 该? I learned it is more formal, but is it used in both colloquial and literary situations?

Comment: 该= that( more literary ) ;  那= that (more colloquial, usually followed by a classifier  )

Answer (score 1):

“这个”多用于口语，“此”多用于书面语尤其是古代文献。但就其所表达的意思上其实并没有区别。

Answer (score 0):

We usually won't use "此" before certain people or things. But it's fine to use "此人" which means this people. And "此物" for this thing.
For myself, I would like to use "此" in writing. Because most time "此" would sound too official. We could see "此" are used more often in news report or some announcements. For example, I always heard "此时此刻" when somebody is making a speech. And others like 此地 此情 此景.